# Getting error while passing json string to Rest service(POST) in C#

Tags: c#, json, rest

I'm trying to send the JSON data to the REST service but getting error. The JSON data is `{"Project":111,"itemType":123,"fields":{"name":"Test","Description":"Tseting only"}}`

Below is the code

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);//I'm passing the url from as a parameter
request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("xxxx:xxxx"));
request.ContentType = "text/json";
request.Method = "POST";
//string names = "praneeth";
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json =
        "{ \"project\": 111," +
        "\"itemType\": 123," +
        "\"fields\":\"{ \"name\":\"Test\"," + "\"description\":\"Testing only\"}\"}";
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sreader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string responsereader = sreader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
```

The error I'm getting is

> {"meta":{"status":"Bad
>   Request","timestamp":"2015-08-04T22:40:55.645+0000","message":"Can not
>   instantiate value of type java.util.LinkedHashMap from String value
>   ('{ '); no single-String constructor/factory method\n at [Source:
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.EntityInputStream@50e3274b;
>   line: 1, column: 33] (through reference chain:
>   com.jamasoftware.contour.rest.v1.domain.RequestItem[\"fields\"])"}}

Comment: Answer is easy, because your json is not valid... Put a breakpoint, get the json you have, and paste it to http://jsonlint.com/. And then start to use a real json parser to form your json strings....

Comment: Step 1) Verify you can hit the web service successfully using a tool such as Postman: https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: @KevinCrowell Look at the source again. Which line can generate this error? Of course it comes from remote end. So we put a green tick for step1. What is next?

Comment: @EZI Thanks for your help. Now I am able to post the data successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the JSON data is this:

```
{"Project":111,"itemType":123,"fields":{"name":"Test","Description":"Tseting only"}}
```

But what you're actually constructing is this:

```
{ "project": 111,"itemType": 123,"fields":"{ "name":"Test","description":"Testing only"}"}
```

Which is not valid JSON.

So, remove those extra quotes.

Answer (score -1):

You are currently sending `fields` as a string, which is not valid for the target type of that property. Take out the encapsulating quotation marks, to send this a object instead.

Such as the following:

```
 string json =
      "{"
       + "\"project\": 111,"
       + "\"itemType\": 123,"
       + "\"fields\": { "
           + "\"name\" : \"Test\","
           + "\"description\":\"Testing only\""
       + "}" +
       "}";
 streamWriter.Write(json);
```

I would also recommend deserializing from your own Object rather than concatenated string literals. This makes forming your JSON a lot easier, and safer.